# reactjs app deployed to heroku with gitlab cicd but app not in prod mode its in dev mode

Tags: reactjs, heroku, gitlab

i have successfully deployed reactjs app to heroku with use of gitlab cicd but when its deployed
it runs in dev mode not prod.
below is config for cicd

`image: node:12.14.1`

stages:
   - build
   - deploy

cache:
   paths:
   - node_modules/

build:
  stage: build
  before_script: 
    - echo "running builds"
  script:
     - npm install
     - npm build

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: ruby:2.4
  before_script:
      - gem install dpl
      - wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh

script:
     - apt-get update -qy
     - apt-get install -y ruby-dev
     - gem install dpl
     - dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_APP_NAME --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY --skip-cleanup

Answer (score -1):

Could you please check in your package.json what config is available for npm script named [build]. This script might be setup with development mode. You basically need to have two npm scripts one with development mode and one with prod mode.And invoke production mode script in ci cd. 
Hope it helps

Comment: what script should i add can you please explan.

Comment: if you could your share package.json or some details about your build tool, I can help.

Comment: how Express helped here to fix this over CI CD? welcome anyway:-)

Comment: i used express to deploy only [build] to prod

Comment: is there any other way ? i would like to know

Comment: {
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
}

Comment: this is scripts i have in package.json